# Which is better way to create multiple directories in Azure file storage?

Tags: java, rest, azure, functional-programming, logic

I am creating application where I need to create one directory inside another. Just like this :
Directory1/Directory2/Directory3/Directory4/Directory5

Here , Directory5 is in Directory4 ,Directory4 is in Directory 3 and so on..

So, I have 2 available options :
1) Call REST API related to 'create directory' in loop which is explained here :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-directory  (I haven't code yet by this logic)

2) Code in java by applying loop to create multiple directories as required. Code like this :

```
public JSONObject createDirectory(JSONObject jsonInput)
            throws IOException, InvalidKeyException, URISyntaxException {

            CloudFileClient fileClient = null;
            String storageConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName="
                    + jsonInput.get("accountName") + ";" + "AccountKey=" + jsonInput.get("accountKey");
            System.out.println(storageConnectionString);
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
            JSONObject jsonOutput = new JSONObject();
            try {
                fileClient = storageAccount.createCloudFileClient();
                String directoryName = jsonInput.get("directoryStructure").toString();

                String[] directoryNameArray = directoryName.split("\\s*/\\s*");
                System.out.println(directoryNameArray.length);

                CloudFileShare share = fileClient.getShareReference(directoryNameArray[0].toLowerCase()
                        .replaceAll("[-+.^:,!@#$%&*()_~`]", "").replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
                if (share.createIfNotExists()) {
                    System.out.println("New container created named as " + directoryNameArray[0].toLowerCase()
                            .replaceAll("[-+.^:,!@#$%&*()_~`]", "").replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
                }
                CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.getRootDirectoryReference();
                for (int i = 0; i < directoryNameArray.length; i++) {
                    String directoryToCreate = directoryNameArray[i];
                    CloudFileDirectory directory = rootDir.getDirectoryReference(directoryToCreate);
                    if (directory.createIfNotExists()) {
                        String token = testDirectorySas(share, rootDir);
                        System.out.println("new directory created named as " + directoryName);
                        jsonOutput.put("token", token);
                        jsonOutput.put("status", "successful");
                    }
                    rootDir = directory;
                }
                if (jsonOutput.containsKey("token")) {
                    return jsonOutput;
                } else {
                    jsonOutput.put("note", "same directory structure already exist");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception is " + e.toString());
                jsonOutput.put("status", "unsuccessful");
                jsonOutput.put("exception", e.toString());
            }
            return jsonOutput;
        }
```

Which one is more preferable way you think and what is the reason? Should I call REST APi in loop or the java code I wrote is OK? Is there any time difference between execution of this two methods?

Comment: SDK actually calls the REST API so it's up to you whether you want to code everything yourself (use REST API in that case) or make use of what's already available to you (use SDK in that case).

Comment: Ok, will it make any effect in execution time of code if I use logic with REST API for same service?

Comment: I don't think so as most part of the execution time will be spent in making the HTTP request (part of REST API) but you should give it a try yourself.

Comment: Ok, will try it. Thanks.